# Schema validation: string from specific list of values

Tags: karate

I have an endpoint with the following response:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "status": "ACTIVE"
   }
```

The possible values for status are the following: ACTIVE, INACTIVE, DELETED. 
To check the schema I tried the following:

```
* def statusValues = ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "DELETED" ]
* def schema = 
"""
{
  "id" : #number,
  "status" : '#(^*statusValues)'
}
"""
```

And to validate I use the following sentence:
    Then match `response == schema`

But it doesn't work. This is the error

> actual: 'ACTIVE', expected: ["DELETED","ACTIVE","INACTIVE"], reason:
>   actual value is not list-like

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the simplest option:

```
* def isValidStatus = function(x){ return statusValues.contains(x) }
* def schema = { id: '#number', status: '#? isValidStatus(_)' }
```