# Karate Fuzzy Matching - Build custom markers

Tags: javascript, java, karate

Is there an easy way to build custom markers in Karate which can be used for Fuzzy Matching?

I would like to extend the list of built-in markers (#uuid, #string, #number, ... - see https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching) with markers which are specific to our project (e.g. #timestamp).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the `#?` marker is for. For an example see this recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57164997/143475

This is explained in detail in the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

Comment: Self-validating expressions using the #? marker is a powerful feature which would indeed solve my issue described above. However, the syntax to use the #? marker is a bit more complicated compare to the predefined markers like e.g. #uuid . I'm currently testing an API which heavily uses UUIDs and Timestamps. In this project I'm very happy about the ease-of-use of #uuid. That's why I was wondering if Karate supports to extend the list of markers (besides using #?).

Comment: @altes-kind I totally saw that coming :) https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/842 - how does that look ?